# Kendo UI grid client template dropdown - update after controller constructor init?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-custom

Hope this is clear.

I have a view that includes a grid with an existing application.  The grid needs to load only after selecting some other inputs in the view.  Using one of the "template" approaches like the above example works if you know what the list will contain ahead of time.  The grid databinds when the view is rendered, and any ClientTemplate is rendered then.  So, rebinding the grid doesnt seem to affect the dropdownlist since it has already been rendered.

However, the contents of the dropdownlist cant be known until the user starts adding items to the grid, so its only then that I to need define whats going to be in the dropdownlist, not from the very beginning when the grid is initially displayed.

How do I define or populate the dropdownlist when the grid is binding or as a result of the read action?

[update]
 This is the grid column in question, where now Ive setup the column to have its own datasource, but the action GetSystemItemCodes never gets invoked. There is a read action on the grid itself (not shown), but since the template has already rendered when the grid is displayed the first time, it doesnt matter what I do to update the viewdata, its already been rendered.

```
columns.Bound(rdetail => rdetail.ItemCode).Title("Item Code").ClientTemplate((@Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .DataSource(datasrc => datasrc.Read(read => read.Action("GetSystemItemCodes", "SalesVoucher")))       
        .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "itemCodeDropDown" })
        .OptionLabel("- Select Item Code - ")
        .DataValueField("ItemCodeID")
        .DataTextField("ItemCodeValue")
        .Name("itemCodeDropDown")
        .Events(e => e.Change("OnItemCodeChange"))
         .ToClientTemplate()).ToHtmlString()).Width(230);
```

I think my next approach will be to filter the dropdown with items being returned when adding a new row.

So suppose my question is at this point is:  when defining a datasource for an individual column this way, when does its read action get called?  Right after the read action on the grid ?  How manually cause the column datasource to refresh or rebind?

Comment: How about ajax-binding: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/ajax-binding

Comment: Take a look the the grid custom editing demo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom.  Here they bind a column to a custom editor function that wires up a dropdownlist "on-demand" that does an ajax call to fetch the data, but could just as easily be bound to any dataSource(local or remote).  Note that this is also the technique you would use if you needed the the dropdown datasource to by dynamic based on other values in the grid as this give you the opportunity to pass additional parameters to the read action(i.e. another cell value).

Comment: Thanks, the example you give is the same one I mentioned and I was trying that approach.  However, as I mentioned this seems to not do what I need since the grid initially has no data and neither will the dropdownlist because the user hasnt selected anything from data elsewhere in the view.  The 2nd approach you mentioned is something Im going to try since upon adding rows to the grid, I could then update the datasource used by the column, or at least that seems to be the idea.

Comment: Well that approach didnt work either.  I think Im going to try another approach where I use the EditorTemplate that was there originally, but filter the dropdownlist using the list of items I get back in my viewmodel when adding a new row.

Comment: Woot!  This is what finally led me to a solution.  http://www.telerik.com/forums/refresh-dropdownlist-inside-kendo-grid  , In summary I went back to using an editor template, then within the OnEdit grid handler, I forced the column datasource to read again.